# NHibernate Like with integer

Tags: nhibernate, sql-like

I have a NHibernate search function where I receive integers and want to return results where at least the beginning coincides with the integers, e.g.

received integer: 729 
returns: 729445, 7291 etc.

The database column is of type int, as is the property "Id" of Foo.

But

```
int id = 729;

var criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Foo))

criteria.Add(NHibernate.Criterion.Expression.InsensitiveLike("Id", id.ToString() + "%"));

return criteria.List<Foo>();
```

does result in an error (Could not convert parameter string to int32). Is there something wrong in the code, a work around, or other solution?

Answer (score 9):

How about this:

```
int id = 729;

var criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Foo))
criteria.Add(Expression.Like(Projections.Cast(NHibernateUtil.String, Projections.Property("Id")), id.ToString(), MatchMode.Anywhere));

return criteria.List<Foo>();
```

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, you'll need to store your integer as a string in the database if you want to use the built in NHibernate functionality for this (I would recommend this approach even without NHibernate - the minute you start doing 'like' searches you are dealing with a string, not a number - think US Zip Codes, etc...).

You could also do it mathematically in a database-specific function (or convert to a string as described in [Thiago Azevedo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937492/nhibernate-like-with-integer/5938978#5938978)), but I imagine these options would be significantly slower, and also have potential to tie you to a specific database.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried something like this:

```
int id = 729;

var criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Foo))

criteria.Add(NHibernate.Criterion.Expression.Like(Projections.SqlFunction("to_char", NHibernate.NHibernateUtil.String, Projections.Property("Id")), id.ToString() + "%"));

return criteria.List<Foo>();
```

The idea is convert the column before using a to_char function. Some databases do this automatically.

Comment: If using this approach it's worth noting that you'll need to use your database's to_char equivalent

Comment: That's correct @AlexCuse. In this example I'm using an oracle8iDialect.

Comment: Any idea what I have to write with SQL Server 2008?

Comment: You'd need to use something like CONVERT(VarChar, MyIntColumn).  Depending on the size of the table this could get very slow though.  Are you ever going to need to use this column as a normal integer (in the database)?

Comment: Exactly, depending on the size of the table this solution is impracticable. Maybe the best solution for you is to create a pseudo column (ie. in a view) converted to string with a index over this column and using it instead of using the ID field.